# Sieve filter that rewrites From to Reply-To to handle Constant Contact lists

Tags: email, dovecot, roundcube, sieve, sieve-language

As a journalist, I deal with a lot of PR companies that use Constant Contact to send out info to their lists of writets. For years, I've built up a nice set of sieve rules that sorts these emails into my PR folder.

I guess to help with deliverability issues, Constant Contact has started rewriting the From header to the sender's address munged to end with a ccsend domain. The sender's actual email address is now in the Reply-To header. This has resulted in all my PR emails ending up in the main inbox instead of the PR folder.

Rather than rewrite hundreds of rules, I thought it might be possible to have the first sieve rule check for ccsend in the from and then rewrite the from to the reply-to so that all my old rules work. I put the following at the beginning of my roundcube.sieve file but it's not working.

`if allof (header :contains "from" "ccsend") { set "from" "${reply-to}"; }  #rest of rules`